# Start/stop systemd service from gnome 3

Tags: systemd, gnome3

I have systemd services on my desktop that don't need to run all the time. So far I start/stop them from the CLI every time I need it.

I'm using Gnome 3 on Fedora 25, is there any way to do it from the GUI? Ideally I would like to have an icon on the top bar that I could use to stop/start the service, as well as have a visual of whether the service is up or down.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: If you know basic `js` it should be piece of cake to [adapt this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1034/services-systemd/) to your needs (it if doesn't already do what you want...)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of starting or stopping a service using an icon, there's already a [spec for ".desktop" files](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en) that Gnome can use to run commands when clicked on.  It doesn't matter that the scripts you happen to want to run are systemd command not something else.

There's also no special shortcut available when it comes to creating a visual indicator menu for a systemd service. Following the general documentation for how to build an indicator is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

As for GUI apps you have following options

1. [systemd-manager](https://github.com/mmstick/systemd-manager) written in rust
2. [Cockpit](http://cockpit-project.org/) a system management service provides web app for managing more than one system

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is old, perhaps the following recommendation will be useful:

[Systemd Manager](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4174/systemd-manager/) ([GitHub Repository link](https://github.com/hardpixel/systemd-manager)) is a Gnome shell extension that allows you to configure a list of services that will appear in the icon list:

[image: screenshot of systemd-manager]